# Does PCRE support unicode string correctly?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, pcre

Does [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) support unicode string correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by Unicode string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does (though probably not Unicode 6 yet). From the [man page](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> The  current implementation of PCRE corresponds approximately with Perl 5.12, including port for UTF-8 encoded strings and  Unicode  general category  properties.  However,  UTF-8  and  Unicode  support has to be explicitly enabled; it is not the default. The  Unicode  tables  correspond to Unicode release 5.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

It supportsc completely `Unicode 5.1`

Answer (score 0):

If your PCRE was compiled without UTF-8 enabled, you can turn it on by adding `(*UTF8)` to the beginning of your regular expression.

For example:

```
> echo ‒ | grep -Po '[‒]'
```

matches each of the 3 utf-8 codes of the character `‒` individually (ie: 3 lines of output), whereas this:

```
> echo ‒ | grep -Po '(*UTF8)[‒]'
```

has the expected result, producing one line of output containing the character `‒`.

(I'm using a stock install of Ubuntu 12.04)